# how many TCP connections used to download 2 MB file?

Tags: networking

Typically, how many TCP connections used to download 2 MB file?
What if the file size was 200 MB, how many connections then?

Answer (score 2):

In general, a single TCP connection is used to transfer a file, regardless of size. This is generally the way it works over http for example; one connection is opened and it stays open for the duration of the transfer. (In fact http can transfer multiple files over the same connection, one after the other).

There are some protocols that can use multiple connections but this generally doesn't depend much on file size. For example, FTP uses one connection for control commands but can use a second connection for each file transfer. Another example is Amazon's AWS client that can "chunk" a large file into separate bits and transfer them in parallel. That's unusual however and in general one file = one connection.